# Error "BlockingClientInFutureContext" when trying to make a request from within an actix-web route handler function

Tags: rust, actix-web, reqwest

I am writing a web service with Rust 2018 Stable and Actix-Web. Using Reqwest, I am making an HTTP request to a diffent site **from within one route handler** function. Simplyfied it looks like this

```
extern crate reqwest;
use actix_web;
use reqwest::Url;

pub fn testing(req: actix_web::HttpRequest) -> actix_web::Result<actix_web::HttpResponse> {
    println!(">>> testing request begin");
    let url = Url::parse("https://example.com/").unwrap();
    println!(">>> testing url built");
    let req = reqwest::Client::new().post(url);
    println!(">>> testing req prepared");
    let res_struct = req.send();
    println!(">>> testing res_struct received");
    let res = res_struct.unwrap();
    println!(">>> testing res unwrapped");
    Ok(format!("done.").into())
}
```

That doesn't work, and I am getting the following error message (the error is printed 8 times, "worker:1" to "worker:8", despite calling the function only once):

```
thread 'actix-rt:worker:1' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` 
on an `Err` value: Error(BlockingClientInFutureContext, 
"https://www.example.com/")', src/libcore/result.rs:999:5
Panic in Arbiter thread, shutting down system.
```

Google didn't find anything useful on *"BlockingClientInFutureContext"*, but I am guessing it is somehow related to async/await or maybe Tokio's own futures?

Thanks for any pointers about what to read up on. Also, I am new to Rust.

The handler function **is called from the Actix-Web HTttpServer**:

```
HttpServer::new(|| App::new().service(
    web::resource("/testing").route(
        web::get().to(views::testing)
    )
)).bind("127.0.0.1:8001")?.run()
```

Comment: I would not think that tokio or async/await would call 'unwrap()'. In you code: `.post(Url::parse(API_ENDPOINT).unwrap())`, you are calling unwrap(), which will result in a panic if the unwrap() fails.  Have you tried changing this to a call that does not use unwrap()?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I updated the question. It panics when unwrapping the reqwest Response.

Comment: I think it would help if you could submit a [mcve], with a main fn so that members can copy and paste your example into their IDE.

Comment: I updated the question with a full example. Almost sure this can be solved with `actix_web::web::block()` somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue. The resolution for me was to lock the Reqwest crate version at 0.9.17 in your cargo file then rebuild.

```
reqwest = "=0.9.17"
```

It appears that newer version of Reqwest are broken with Actix-web unless you're using the async functionality on both. For reference: https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/issues/541

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, `actix_web::web::block()` was the correct guess. Using it makes it possible to make blocking calls. `block()` returns a Future that resolves once the network request returns data. Very close to Promises in JS, plus the `.from_err()` in there.

```
pub fn testing(_req: actix_web::HttpRequest)
    -> impl Future<Item = HttpResponse, Error = Error>
{
    println!(">>> testing request begin");
    let url = Url::parse("https://example.com/").unwrap();
    println!(">>> testing url built");
    let req = reqwest::Client::new().get(url);
    println!(">>> testing req prepared");

    actix_web::web::block(move || {
        println!(">>> testing res received");
        req.send()
    })
    .from_err()
    .and_then(|res| {
        println!(">>> testing res: {:?}", &res);
        HttpResponse::Ok().content_type("text/html").body("Hello!")
    })
}
```

Additionally, in `main.rs` the route must be called using `.to_async()` instead of simply `.to()`:

```
HttpServer::new(|| App::new().service(
    web::resource("/testing").route(
        web::get().to_async(views::testing)
    )
)).bind("127.0.0.1:8001")?.run()
```

Comment: Thanks, I almost wasted a day for this problem, but this solution doesn't work with std::future, does it? since future crate has been yanked I don't know how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Upgrade to reqwest 0.9.22 or newer.

The error is indicating that you're attempting to make a blocking network call from inside an asynchronous context (Actix Web handlers are called asynchronously). This is not supported in reqwest versions 0.9.17 - 0.9.21.

As of 0.9.22, the author has removed this error in favor of a warning. For more information:

https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/pull/670

https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/issues/541

Answer (score 0):

The call to `unwrap()` is failing because an error is returned.  It is best to avoid `unwrap()` in production code because it usually means we are trying to look at the 'desired' value (often called the 'happy path') while ignoring the error path.

This code works:

```rust
use actix_web;
use reqwest::Url;

fn main()  {
    println!(">>> testing request begin");
    let url = Url::parse("http:/example.com/").unwrap();
    println!(">>> testing url built");
    let req = reqwest::Client::new().post(url);
    println!(">>> testing req prepared");
    let res_struct = req.send();
    println!(">>> testing res_struct received");
    match res_struct {
        Ok(r)=> println!("response: {:?}", r),
        Err(e)=> println!("error: {}", e),
    }
//    let res = res_struct.unwrap();
    println!("done.");
}
```

The output is:

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2.63s
     Running `target/debug/untitled`
>>> testing request begin
>>> testing url built
>>> testing req prepared
>>> testing res_struct received
error: http://example.com/: error trying to connect: failed to lookup address information: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
>>> testing res unwrapped
done.
```

The above code works without a panic, but the server at `example.com` is not providing a good response.
If I re-run this using a valid URL, e.g. https://cisco.com, I get no errors:

```html
>>> testing request begin
>>> testing url built
>>> testing req prepared
>>> testing res_struct received
response: Response { url: "https://www.cisco.com/", status: 200, headers: {"server": "Apache", "etag": "\"1732e-59058880c8465\"", "accept-ranges": "bytes", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000", "cdchost": "wemxweb-publish-prod2-02", "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block", "x-test-debug": "nURL=www.cisco.com,realm=0,isRealm=0,realmDomain=0,shortrealm=0", "content-security-policy": "upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors *.cisco.com *.jasper.com *.ciscospark.com *.ciscolive.com  http://cisco.lookbookhq.com https://cisco.lookbookhq.com testcisco.marketing.adobe.com cisco.marketing.adobe.com ciscosales.my.salesforce.com test.salesforce.com zedo.com hindustantimes.com economictimes.indiatimes.com *.webex.com *.cdw.com *.cdwg.com *.cdw.ca *.meraki-go.com http://ciscopartners.lookbookhq.com https://ciscopartners.lookbookhq.com ciscolearningsystem.com ciscocustomer.lookbookhq.com cisco.lookbookhq.com;", "content-type": "text/html", "expires": "Sun, 18 Aug 2019 12:10:23 GMT", "cache-control": "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store", "pragma": "no-cache", "date": "Sun, 18 Aug 2019 12:10:23 GMT", "connection": "keep-alive", "vary": "Accept-Encoding"} }
>>> testing res unwrapped
done.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am still getting the same error: `error: https://cisco.com/: blocking Client used inside a Future context`. This is run within a request handler, called from the Actix-Web router, not simply from a regular `main()` function.

Comment: I guess your [mcve] needs to be expanded a little :-).

Comment: I mentioned several times that this is a Actix-Web Request Handler function. And I even posted how to set up the standard Actix Web router on `HttpServer`. How can I make it more clear? The Question is tagged with "Actix-Web" for that very reason.